# What do u use to set as username?

Tags: apex, community, facebook, twitter

I have an app which built on Salesforce platform, need to support feature login using facebook/twitter. As far as i know we can't get username of facebook/twitter passed in Auth.UserData data object (because it doesn't allow us). So what did you guys use to set for username value ? i know we can use a random string generated from identifier but do you have any workaround to make a human-readable username?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb I keep username as equivalent to email.For communities especially this is true since username is not unique across orgs.

Comment: thanks @Mohith Shrivastava. But Fb don't allow us to get email of user. And sometimes, people don't need email to register Facebook account, they can do with their phone number. Do you have any other solution ?

Comment: Use first name . lastname@yourcompany.com